# API controller POST method multipart/form-data using boundary get message inside the body

Tags: c#, controller, multipartform-data, .net-5, boundary

I'm having trouble developing a C# (.Net 5) method on an API controller who can manage request who have 'multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary'

I can't change the request on the client side, I only can modify my backend to adapt to it.

The request specify the 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary', and it has a json message inside the body that I need to extract.

Inside the body of the request the message is like this:

```
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ZZZZZZZZZZ"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 474

{
    //a well formed json
}
--boundary--
```

I can get that using this code: `string dataMessage = new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync().Result;`

Then I can manually parse that string to extract only the json part using IndexOf and Substring, and then cast it to an object using JsonConvert.

**I'm wondering if there is some option on .Net to do this automatically without the manual parsing of the string.** I think that there must be some way to interpret the boundary token and get the json data directly. But i can't found any :( That came to my mind because when using webhook.site to test the client request, it can parse the message without any problems.

My controller definition is like this

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class XXXXController : ControllerBase
```

And the method is like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
public IActionResult YYYYYYY()
```

I already tried to specify the model binding to change the behaviour but I can't get it working.

And I already search help before asking:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#model-binding-for-http-get-requests
- https://forums.asp.net/t/2162362.aspx?Read+POST+data+in+request+body
- [How to get POST data in WebAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832784/how-to-get-post-data-in-webapi)
- [how to read multi part form data in .net web api controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545788/how-to-read-multi-part-form-data-in-net-web-api-controller)
- [ASP.NET MVC. How to create Action method that accepts and multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357982/asp-net-mvc-how-to-create-action-method-that-accepts-and-multipart-form-data)
- [415 Unsupported Media Type when uploading "multipart/form-data" to .Net Core 3.1 API but the file is accessible in middleware method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65560901/415-unsupported-media-type-when-uploading-multipart-form-data-to-net-core-3-1)
- [ASP.NET Core form POST results in a HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538772/asp-net-core-form-post-results-in-a-http-415-unsupported-media-type-response)
- [ASP.NET How read a multipart form data in Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632028/asp-net-how-read-a-multipart-form-data-in-web-api)
- [How to send multipart/form-data to ASP.NET Core Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411250/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-to-asp-net-core-web-api)
- [How to set up a Web API controller for multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369529/how-to-set-up-a-web-api-controller-for-multipart-form-data)
- [Send POST request through WebClient with boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347979/send-post-request-through-webclient-with-boundary)
- [Web API Simplest way to pickup a multipart/form-data response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250721/web-api-simplest-way-to-pickup-a-multipart-form-data-response)
- [How to get Json Post Values with asp.net webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120971/how-to-get-json-post-values-with-asp-net-webapi/13128879#13128879)
- [What is the boundary in multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data)
- [C# HTTP POST with Boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091208/c-sharp-http-post-with-boundary)
- [How to set MIME type for POST - multipart/form-data in axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550834/how-to-set-mime-type-for-post-multipart-form-data-in-axios)

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't built-in support of `multi-part/form-data` Media Type in .Net5 by default. So, the input formatter should be attached to the `MvcBuilder`.

Considering the fact that you can't manipulate client-side, [**ApiMultipartFormDataFormatter**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ApiMultipartFormDataFormatter/) which enables this type of input formatting can be utilized.

1. Add the Package:

> Install-Package ApiMultipartFormDataFormatter -Version 3.0.0

2. Configure the Formatter in `Startup.cs`

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddControllers(options =>
       {
           options.InputFormatters.Add(new MultipartFormDataFormatter());
       });
   }
   ```
3. Assuming the mentioned well formed json is something like below class:

   ```
   public class CustomContent
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   So, we need to wrap it up into another class that contains this as a parameter.
   **Note:** The library doesn't support deserialization by this moment So, a  getter-only property is added to the model which returns the deserialized object.

   ```
   public class ViewModel
   {
       // Equivalent to ZZZZZZZZZZ
       public string SerializedContent { get; set; }
       public CustomContent Content => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SerializedContent)
           ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomContent>(SerializedContent)
           : null;
   }
   ```
4. Reform the Action to accept the wrapper model.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("[action]")]
   public IActionResult Parse(ViewModel vm)
   {            
       return Ok($"Received Name: {vm?.Content?.Name}");
   }
   ```

The working cURL request of the corresponding example is:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:25599/api/MultiPart/Parse' 

\
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary' \
--data-raw '--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SerializedContent"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 100

{
    "Name" : "Foo"
}
--boundary--'
```

The response should be equal to `Received Name: Foo`.

Comment: A.Mokhtari your answer is amazing, thank you very much. I am changing the code so it is according to what you indicated and I am going to test it :)

Comment: Hope it was helpful. There is also a better but time-consuming solution to eliminate extra wrapper by adding new implementation of `IModelBinderService` into [ApiMultipartFormDataFormatter](https://github.com/redplane/ApiMultipartFormFormatter/tree/master/lib/ApiMultipartFormDataFormatter/Services/Implementations) to enable direct deserialization.